# linux -- getting from /proc/partitions contents to something I can 'ls'

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

I am writing (yet another) file manager (to learn stuff:) and have a silly/stupid block.

On Linux, to enumerate the storage devices which can contain files, I believe the best approach is to parse the contents of the /proc/partitions file and extract the /dev/sda* entries.  (right?)  However, how can I map the /dev/sda* to something that I can explore programmatically to get directory contents?  I am planning on using boost/filesystem, but since I cannot ls /dev/sda I assume I cannot use boost to iterate over it.

Synopsis:  how can I convert /dev/sda* to something that I can 'ls'

Comment: To browse a filesystem, it needs to be mounted. To get a mapping of block device (sdXY) to mount point, try looking at the /etc/mtab file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mis-understanding exactly what `/dev/sd*` actually are to a program.  They are *devices* not directories.  You use the `mount` command to tell the operating system to "interpret" the device as a filesystem, and to attach it somewhere (root, or otherwise).  It's this step that makes it into "a directory" somewhere on your filesystem.  So other than raw I/O commands (which you don't want to do), get the filesystem mounted, and THEN try and explore it.

It's kind of like opening a file really.  When you do this, the operating system gives your program a stream of bytes that you can randomly access the file through.  But on the disk, that file could actually be scattered all over the hard drive (or whatever device).  But the OS is "making" it into a "nice" format for you to deal with transparently.  The same is true of the disk itself when accessing directory/file listings.

I hope my example made it clearer as to why what you're trying to do isn't as simple as you think it is.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I learned something from everybody!  Thank you all very much

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff, I'd say that the output of `mount` with no arguments might be a faster choice. That should show you the mounted filesystems and devices while /proc would show you all the devices and partitions.

Answer (score 1):

the device `/dev/sda*` is a block device and needs to be mounted. To be able to `ls` it you need to have something that can interpret the file system type. First step: identify the file system type, in raw code there is usually a header code in the partition table in the first segment of the harddrive which would just be `/dev/sda` On a Linux system it would be something like `ext3`

Next you need to either write or use a library for interfacing with that filesystem, if you get the Kernel source code for Linux it has a LOT of API code for interfacing with common filesystems, and wrappers for standard POSIX calls which is exactly what you're looking for.  Things like `ls` and `cwd` use system calls to retrieve information about a mounted filesystem, the disk is a block (or sometimes a character) device and you need the ability to talk to it and speak the same language.